# CCGLView flicker issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocos2d-iphone, cocos3d

I have a CCGLView in my viewController, after completing the animations I'm trying to replace scene in the CCGLView with an empty scene. The issue is that while replacing the scene there is a flicker which I can observe. I want to avoid it, I'm providing the code below. What I have to change to avoid that flicker?

```
CC3Layer* layer=[[CC3Layer alloc]init];
CC3Scene* scene= (CC3Scene*)layer.scene;
scene.backdrop= [CC3Backdrop nodeWithColor:ccc4f(0.0/255.0, 0.0/255.0, 0.0/255.0, 0.0)];
[scene updateScene];
[self.director replaceScene:[layer asCCScene] withTransition:[CCTransition transitionCrossFadeWithDuration:1.0]];
[self.director stopAnimation];
```

Answer (score 0):

One issue is that the `scene` property of `CC3Layer` returns the `CCScene` instance, and not the `CC3Scene` instance you are expecting. In any case, in your code, the  `scene` property will return `nil`, because it has not yet been set. Try using the `cc3Scene` property, instead.

You haven't indicated where you are trying to run this code, but if I add the following code to the `nodeSelected:byTouchEvent:at:` method of the `CC3HelloWorld` template app, the transition runs smoothly, without any kind of flicker:

```
CC3Layer* layer=[[CC3Layer alloc]init];
CC3Scene* scene= layer.cc3Scene;
scene.backdrop= [CC3Backdrop nodeWithColor:ccc4f(0.0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0)];
[CCDirector.sharedDirector replaceScene:[layer asCCScene] withTransition:[CCTransition transitionCrossFadeWithDuration:1.0]];
```

...Bill